# Get latitude and longitude given name and address

Tags: google-places-api, google-latitude

I have a CSV file with name,area,city fieds and I'm expecting that CSV with following fields name,area,city,latitude,longitude

Can any one suggest which API is best for these,

I already tried
Google API's

1. Textsearch: this is giving overall city wise. Not particular
   eg: kfc, in jp nagar 1st phase, bangalore it throws all over bangalore kfc list

I want exactly

```
echo  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $name1 . "+" . $area1 . "+" . $city . "&key=" . $api_key;
```

Which API will fulfill my requirement?

I tried this also

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=". $name1 . "+" . $area1 . "+" . $city . "&key=" . $api_key;
```